A factory has a batch of hand sanitiser with 50% alcohol content. How much pure alcohol should they include in a 600 mL bottle to make a 68% mixture?

A factory has a batch of hand sanitiser with 50% alcohol content. How much pure alcohol should they include in a 600 mL bottle to make a 68% mixture?

I thought: simple enough, the factory has
$$
0.5 = \frac{300}{600}.
$$
They need to figure out how much more alcohol to mix; therefore,
$$
0.68 = \frac{300+x}{600} \Rightarrow x = 108\text{ mL}.
$$
But the answer is
$$
0.68 = \frac{300+0.5x}{600} \Rightarrow x = 216\text{ mL}.
$$
I can't figure out what I have done wrong.

Let's just clarify for everybody that the symbol for a litre is $l$, not $L$. All SI symbols which are not derived from a proper name are lower case.

@jcaron I'm used to ml too, but both ml and mL are actually in use. P.S. I rejected your edit to my answer below simply just to stick to the OP's choice.

I don't really have a dog in this fight. I just copied as is from the source of problem.



A factory has a batch of hand sanitiser with 50% alcohol content. How much pure alcohol should they include in a 600 mL bottle to make a 68% mixture?


Let $x$ mL be the volume of pure alcohol to be added to the $50\%$ ABV sanitiser to obtain the required mixture. Then the amount of alcohol to be contributed by the hand sanitiser is $\frac12(600-x)$ mL, that is, half of the sanitiser's volume. So,
$$0.68=\frac{x+\frac12(600-x)}{600}\\x=216.$$

$$0.68 = \frac{300+x}{600} \Rightarrow x = 108\text{ mL}.$$

Note that

the symbol ⇒ means 'implies', not 'therefore'; your presentation just says that if the left side is true, then the right side is the answer; it doesn't actually assert that the right side is the answe;
$x$ cannot both be a pure number and be a physical quantity with unit mL.

A coherent presentation (though not the correct answer) is $$0.68 = \frac{300+x}{600}; \text{thereore, }x = 108$$ or just $$0.68 = \frac{300+x}{600}\\x = 108.$$

I just meant that "if $f(x) = a$ holds, then $x=b$. In this case we might even get away with an if and only if.

@scribe Observe that neither "I'm going to the pictures iff it is Monday" nor "if it's Monday I'm going to the pictures" actually asserts that I'm going to the pictures. The information given in the above exercise is a given, so doesn't need to be presented as a hypothetical (as if there are other hypothetical cases to consider). "A implies B" is a logically weaker assertion than "we know that A is true; therefore B must also be true (since A implies B)". Using ⇒ to mean therefore seems to be the later equivalent of using = to mean output (1 + 2 = 3 + 4 = 7).

On the other hand, it does make perfect sense to write "$f(x)=a⇔x=b$
" (when merely solving the LHS equation, we are just considering the specific case of $f$
attaining the value $a,$
and not claiming that $f(x)$
is a constant function) or "$f(x)=a⇒x=b$
".

Doesn't an addition of $x$ amount of alcohol increase the total volume? Shouldn't it be $\frac{300+x}{600+x}=.68\implies .32x=108\implies x= 337.5$?

@JohnDouma You've misread the question as "How much pure alcohol should they add to a 600 mL bottle to make a 68% mixture?"

To keep the volume constant when you add $x$ ml of pure alcohol, you must remove $x$ ml of the sanitizer. Since half of the sanitizer is alcohol, you are removing $0.5x$ ml of alcohol before adding $x$ ml of alcohol. The net alcohol content is $300-0.5x+x=300+0.5x$ ml.

It can be done without Algebra, using inverse proportion , as the ratio of pure alcohol$\,:\,$sanitizer needed to get the target
will be in inverse proportion to their distance from target, so $(68-50):(100-68) = 18:32 = 9:16$
Thus Pure alcohol needed $= \frac{9}{(9+16)} \times 600 = 216 ml$

$\underline{\texttt{Addressing OP's Query}}$
Suppose you have stocks of $60\%$ alcohol and $30\%$ alcohol  and want to make a $200$ ml cocktail with $45\%$ alcohol
Alcohol: $30\% ---------- 45\% - - - - - - - - - - 60\%$
Since $45$ is the mid-point of $30$ and $60$ it is obvious that $100$ ml of each will be needed
But what if we want the cocktail to have $50\%$ alcohol ?
Alcohol: $30\% -------------50\% - - - - - - - - 60\%$
Obviously now we shall need more of the $60\%$ alcohol and the new ratio won't be $15:15$ but $20:10 = \; 2:1$, so in inverse proportion to their respective distances from the target, directly giving the answer of $\frac23\cdot200 ml$ of $60\%$ alcohol
This method is not only faster, but less error prone than using Algebra, where students are more prone to making mistakes.

Algebra  is a versatile tool (yet you did err). Particularly if you come across mixture problems frequently, you must learn this inverse proportion method.

I'd love to learn your way but maybe explain your proportion setup a bit more?

I will add something in the answer itself shortly

You made a query, and I responded. is it  now clear ?

Yes, it is! My apologies. Took me a while to read it properly.

Hoping it may be of help to you in some future  exam. You can find more details amd methods at https://bodheeprep.com/mixture-and-alligation
